# Refresh mainviewController after changes objective-c

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, refresh

I want to reload(refresh) my mainviewcontroller after changes. I add some data to data model and after save operation I put buttons to data elements on my main view. In second controller I make a edition section in which I change or delate data from base. My question is: How can I reload main view after delating element from base. My code for creating buttons is in mainviewcontroller:

```
 NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Destination" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error = nil;
    mutableFetchResults = [[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];

    CGFloat y = 130.;

    for (int i = 0; i < [mutableFetchResults count]; i++) {


        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"ikonki%d.png",i]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


        [button setTitle:@"Test"  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"%@",_destination3.nazwa);
        [button setTitleColor: [UIColor whiteColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setEnabled:YES];

        [button addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(buttonHandler:) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        button.tag = i;
        button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 64 , 64);
```

Comment: When I start up application once again in main view are only icons which should be on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know `NSFetchedResultsController`? Go to documentation and look at *DataSectionTitles* and *iPhoneCoreDataRecipes* samples. Here you can find how to use this class. Basically this class gets your fetch request, listens for changes and if you delete / insert / update / ... objects in your `NSManagedObjectContext` it triggers delegate methods where you can update your view.